# How can I make a callback on Async funcion?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following code which check the user_id if available and then log me in but it logs me in only if I refresh the app. Any idea how to make this happen without this?

This is the order of functions:

First when you click the login button from `Login.js`:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit(_signIn)} style={{margin: 10, alignItems: 'center'}}>
```

then `_signIn` function which is in `Login.js`

```
_signIn = (values, dispatch) => {
  const email = values.email;
  const password = values.password;
  dispatch(loginUser(email, password));
}
```

Now we dispatched email and password to `loginUser` from `authActions.js`

```
export function loginUser(email, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.post(SIGNIN_URL, { email, password }).then((response) => {
      var { user_id, token } = response.data;
      onSignIn(user_id); // Here I pass 'user_id' to onSignIn function
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(addAlert("Could not log in."));
    });
  };
}
```

Now we get the `user_id` from `loginUser` inside `Auth.js`

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

const USER_KEY = "auth_key";

export const onSignIn = (user_id) => AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, user_id);
export const onSignOut = () => AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);

export const isSignedIn = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_KEY)
      .then(res => {
        if (res !== null) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
};
```

Now in `App.js` I am calling the function `isSignedIn` to check if `user_id` is available and if so will choose which screen to show

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      signedIn: false,
      checkedSignIn: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    isSignedIn()
      .then(res => this.setState({ signedIn: res, checkedSignIn: true }))
      .catch(err => alert("An error occurred"));
  }

  render() {
    const { checkedSignIn, signedIn } = this.state;

    // If we haven't checked AsyncStorage yet, don't render anything (better ways to do this)
    if (!checkedSignIn) {
      return null;
    }

    const Layout = createRootNavigator(signedIn);
```

Comment: Seems like you should provide the login code.

Comment: @CodyG. please see my updated code

Comment: It appears to me you're missing `return` in `return onSignIn(user_id);`

Comment: @CodyG. Doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Well, now the next code you should provide is your use of `loginUser` and `isSignedIn`

Comment: @CodyG. `loginUser` takes the values email and password then return a user_id and token as you can see. Then the user_id is used in `onSignIn` function and then `isSignedIn` use this to check if the value is there to take me to the next screen or not.

Comment: Yeah I think that's where your problem is. psuedo code: `loginUser(values).then(onSignin).then(isSignedIn)` <- somewhere in here you are probably not returning a promise correctly. The next time you log into the app it probably works because it IS performing the function, it's just not waiting for the result correctly before you call `isSignedIn`

Comment: [Your isSignedIn function needs to be rewritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @CodyG. please review the order of my functions

Comment: @MarkusHayner Seems okay, but when you mount the component and then they log in, does it update the state? (as Kos has suggested lower)

Comment: @CodyG. It updates the state but I need to call somehow `componentDidMount()` again and have no idea how

Answer (score 0):

It`s not async function callback issue - I do know how to use it, coz you are already use it in the `isSignedIn` function.

You did called `onSignIn(userId)`, but you inform nobody about it. Those function, that calls `isSignedIn` should somehow know about a user logged in.

Based on this issue and previous one, I guess you should choose an architecture of your app (redux or just functional programming or something else) and keep it in mind.
If you wanna use redux, you should dispatch an action about a user logged in and reflect to state change where you need it.

Comment: Agreed. Looks like the problem is that you check `isSignedIn()` when the app mounts - that is, before the user signs in - and don't check it again. State management solution would help here, so that App can be notified when the user gets logged in.

Comment: @Kos I've checked the order of functions and you are right. Now my question is how do I call `isSignedIn()` from mount after I am passing the `user_id` inside `Auth.js`?

Comment: @MarkusHayner it\`s not about an order of functions - it\`s about state management. There is how redux work - it is a state, that get changes by actions and has a subscriptions to the changes.  
See `react-redux->connect->mapStateToProps` to clarify how to get renewed value to a component from the state.